# Insert records from google BigQuery to BigQuery table via Simba ODBC?

Tags: excel, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, odbc, simba

How can I use the Simba ODBC driver to export and insert the records from an Excel file into a BigQuery table?
I tried with VBA ODBC, but it seems to not be working.

Can someone help me with the VBA code if you have exported and inserted the records from the Excel file into the BigQuery table?

Comment: Do these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/bigquery/how-to-connect-bigquery-to-microsoft-excel-and-other-apps-with-our-new-odbc-driver) and [link2](https://medium.com/@mattgazzano/connect-to-bigquery-data-in-excel-with-odbc-no-code-required-6fc8f7969a91) help you?